# Equivalent of SELECT FROM WHERE on Excel

Tags: excel, database

I have a dataset on an Excel table in which each line has an Id and several other columns.
in some others sheets I need to select some columns depending on the given id.

I am using Excel 2016, so I've tried the "dget" function but it seems not to be the best solution.

For the dataset it's close to this:

```
id  Name    birth date  gendre
1   Sara    10/05/1997  F
2   Edward  01/08/1994  M
3   Anna    06/10/1993  F
```

and for getting data I use

```
=DGET(Table1[#All];Table2[[#Headers];[Name]];A1:A2)
```

in each column (A1:A2 here is for id and 2)

```
id  Name    salary 
2   Edward  5000
```

and then I add some new columns that I don't want them to be in the first dataset.

This solution works only for the first row since it requires a the Criteria (last field in DGET function) to be a range, the official definition: 
Criteria Required. The range of cells that contains the conditions that you specify. You can use any range for the criteria argument, as long as it includes at least one column label and at least one cell below the column label in which you specify a condition for the column.

Starting from the second row the Criteria  is not a range anymore it is like "A1;A3" (for the 1st row "A1:A2")

Is there any other solution or alternative to do so?

Comment: DGET isn't really that flexible, and I'd recommend some other functions like match, vlookup and index

Answer (score -1):

Select a cell in the Table, click Insert>PivotTable, then drag the ID, Name, BirthDate, and Gender fields into the ROWS area. Then add a Slicer on ID, Name, and Salary by clicking in the PivotTable and selecting Insert Slicer. Then choose the ID/Name/Salary values you want. To make multiple selections, hold down Ctrl or click the MultiSelect button of the Slicer.